# open a file, hash string, and close - in MacOS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, file-conversion

how do I open a file of strings, hash the strings, and close it in bash?
I am using MacOS X Yosemite.

Comment: What have you tried - and why in bash - a scripting language would be easier and what do you mean by hash

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit short on details, but assuming that you have a file `FILE.txt` where all the strings which need to be hashed are on separate lines, you could run something like

```
: > FILE.hash
while read line; do
    md5 -rs "$line" >> FILE.hash
done < FILE.txt
```

This results in a text file `FILE.hash` containing lines like

```
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3 "hello world"
```

If you prefer to have the hashes without the text they represent, use

```
    md5 -qs "$line" >> FILE.hash
```

instead.